# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'PushNotifications.register') - Capacitor 3

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, deprecated

I've been trying to implement push notifications in my Ionic/React app, however I'm having an issue importing the package and using it in my component. The example [here (Step 4)](https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-in-ionic-react-capacitor/111/) suggests importing it like below

```
import { PushNotification, PushNotificationActionPerformed, PushNotificationToken } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';

const {PushNotifications} = Plugins;
```

Then calling a push method which handles the logic of the PushNotifications plugin.

```
push() {

    PushNotifications.register();

    // On succcess, we should be able to receive notifications
    PushNotifications.addListener('registration',
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      }
    );

    // Some issue with your setup and push will not work
    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError',
      (error: any) => {
        alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );

    // Show us the notification payload if the app is open on our device
    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
      (notification: PushNotification) => {
        console.log(`Notification received: ${notification}`);
      }
    );

    // Method called when tapping on a notification
    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
        console.log(`Notification tapped: ${notification}`);
      }
    );
  }
```

However doing this and running the app gives me an error saying

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'PushNotifications.register')
```

It's worth noting that all the imports say they're deprecated with a line-strike across each of them, but I'm not sure where the working ones are or how to import them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.